# do a conditional check on an evaluated and formatted cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

With google spreadsheets, I have cells with calculated dates, then I have another cell that is simply: `=<cell>`, then formatted to show the day of the week.

Example:

- A, B, C, D

  1: `1/1`, `=A1+1`, `=B1+1`, `=C1+1`

  2: `=A1`, `=B1`, `=C1`, `=D1`

Resulting values:

2, `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`

Then I have another field that is the conditional:
3, `=IF(A2="Sunday",20,40)`

What I would expect to happen:
A3 = 20.

What actually happens: A3 = 40.

Now for comparison's sake, I go back to A2 and manually put in `Sunday`, then A3 now = 20.

So my question is, how can I do a conditional check on an evaluated and formatted value?

Comment: just changing the formatting does not change the value: `=IF(text(A2,"dddd")="Sunday",20,40)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this WEEKDAY function,

```
=IF(weekday(A2)=1,20,40)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked great.
My whole formula now looks like this: `=IF(weekday(E20)=6,D20+3,IF(weekday(E20)=2,D20+3,D20+1))`